# Tag / Autocomplete Software Similar to How Tags Function on all the StackExchange Sites

Tags: javascript, jquery, autocomplete

I'm looking for recommendations on how to get tagging to look as closely as possible to how they look here on the StackExchange sites, including the autocomplete box that appears below the tag input field.  I started with [tag-it](http://aehlke.github.io/tag-it/) as it was highly recommended but I found that it didn't have name/value functionality built-in (showing labels but storing IDs).  There are workarounds you can find on SO showing how to make this happen but it'd be nice to find a plugin that has this feature already built-in, that led me to [select2](https://select2.github.io/).  Select2 is very nice but I would rather have the autocomplete box that appears below the field to look more like the one on the StackExchange sites...

[image]

I couldn't find any information on what StackExchange actually uses.  I doubt it's a single jQuery/JavaScript plugin or I would have found it.  I don't mind using multiple plugins, I just want the end result to resemble StackExchange tagging, at least as much as possible.  Recommendations appreciated, thanks!

Comment: He is an example of an Autocomplete UI like the StackExchange UI - you need to integrate into your tagging system http://jsplayground.syncfusion.com/kj1qj04y